# curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position x

Tags: curl

Im coding while reading a book and I need to write this on the console:

`curl "http://localhost:3000/graphql" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" --data-binary "{"query":"query {\n about\n}\n"}" -compressed{"data":{"about":"Hello World!"}}`

but it returns me the error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgFYu.png) (the bold is the character that returns me the error.)

`curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1:{`**\**`n`

I have tried:

`curl "http://localhost:3000/graphql" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" --data-binary "{\"query\":\"query {\n about\n}\n\"}" –compressed{\"data\":{\"about\":\"Hello World!\"}}`

but it gives me the error: [This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5esTL.png) (the bold is the character that returns me the error.)

`curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 8: World!"`**}**`}`

I think is probably the syntax but I dont know, Im kind of stuck here :{

Comment: As you found out, the first snippet is missing some backslashes; alternately you could have enclosed the whole JSON in single quotes, leaving double quotes inside the JSON. Furthermore, `-compressed` should have two dashes, and should be followed by a space. And `{\"data\":{\"about\":\"Hello World!\"}` is not an URL; no idea what that's supposed to be (you already have the JSON payload supplied through the `--data-binary` option).

Comment: @Amadan true, I fogot the double dashes in `-compressed` and the space, thanks :). Im kind of a begginer in this topic, can you explain the "is not an URL" part?, sometimes I follow the steps of the book but I mostly learn more by running the code.

Comment: [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) that `curl` expects will most likely be a webpage address, such as e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74621159/curl-3-unmatched-close-brace-bracket-in-url-position-x?noredirect=1#comment131716484_74621159` (URL of this page). You are asking `curl` to send a request to a web server; but `{\"data\":{\"about\":\"Hello World!\"}` is not an address of a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of funny, so this was on the book:

`curl "http://localhost:3000/graphql" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" --data-binary "{"query":"query {\n about\n}\n"}" -compressed{"data":{"about":"Hello World!"}}`

it was all joined, the snippet that goes in the CMD is just

`curl "http://localhost:3000/graphql" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" --data-binary "{"query":"query {\n about\n}\n"}" -compressed`

and it returned:

`{"data":{"about":"Hello World!"}}`

from a snippet I modified in a sandbox in Apollo...

So..., its a little embarrassing but I'm going to leave it here as a reminder xD